# How to display data in slickgrid having double quote(") or backslash(\)?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I have a string to display on slickgrid cell 
ex: "my test  "on" \slick grid"
This string gets loaded only after changing  "my test on slick grid".

I am sending to load into grid as Json format. how to fix this error.

Comment: post relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what JSON encoder/decoder you're using. You first need to check that these characters are making it to the client side JSON intact.

SlickGrid should be able to display these character without any issues. The later releases of the grid use the `.html` function in jQuery to display the text, which automatically HTML Encodes the output.

You may want to use [my repo](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid), as it's much more up to date.
Try entering those chars into an edit box [here](http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html), and check the display.